# GET Request fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, python

I want to communicate with my javascript code so I created something which prints `lol: text` out in the Python console.

It works, but it fires multiple times even tough I call it just one time.

The server uses SimpleHTTPServer.
Code:

```
def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.startswith('/test'):
            print 'lol:',
            parsed = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query)
            test = parsed['test'][0]
            print test
```

Javascript code:

```
    function log(txt)
    {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "/test?test=" + txt;
    xhr.open(method,url,true);
    xhr.send();
    }
```

Output:

```
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
lol: g
```

Comment: What server are you using to host your endpoint? Flask? Cherrypy? DJango? These types of details will definitely help you in getting an answer as the problem may not be related to the snips you've provided :-)

Comment: I just attempted to re-create your issue with XMLHttpRequest in Firefox Developers Edition against the [health endpoint](https://github.com/fritogotlayed/corp-hq-api/blob/master/api/controllers/health.py) of an app I already have and was not able to reproduce your issue. Can you provide more details about your setup? Also, re-creating this in a paired down app may be useful. Basically a [Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Prints out lol:text where?  In a browser?  On a printer?  On the server?  If browser, show the rest of your javascript code (like, the code that prints it out, the code that starts the request, etc)

Comment: It uses SimpleHTTPServer and it prints on the Python console.